# How to use loop in Jquery to add table multiple times into div

Tags: jquery

I want to add table multiple time (based on drop down list selected value) into div tag. I used below code and it is displaying only one table row. Can any one guide me to implement this scenario?

```
<select id="ddl">
                    <option value="1">1 </option>
                     <option value="2">2 </option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                       <option value="4">4 </option>
                       <option value="5">5 </option>
             </select>

    <table id="dis">

    <tr>
           <td> 
            <select id="fieldname1">
                    <option value="1"> 1</option>
                     <option value="2">2 </option>
                      <option value="S3">3</option>
                       <option value="S4">4 </option>
                       <option value="AA">5 </option>
             </select>
           </td> 
       <td> 
            <select id="fieldname2">
                    <option value="1">1 </option>
                     <option value="2">2 </option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                       <option value="4">4 </option>
                       <option value="A">A </option>
             </select>
           </td> 
        </tr>
   </table>

<div id="dynamicgroup"> </div>

<script>
     $("#ddl").change(function () {

         var count = parseInt($(this).val());


for (var i = 0; i <count; i++) {


             $('#dynamicgroup').append($('#dis'));


         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You are trying to append `dis` table everytime and this will replace the same table in `div`, instead you can put its clonned copy. use `.clone()` and then append it to `div`

```
$("#ddl").change(function () {
    var count = parseInt($(this).val());
    for (var i = 0; i <count; i++) {
        $('#dynamicgroup').append($('#dis').clone().removeAttr("id"));
     }
});
```

Comment: It also might be a good idea to remove the ID from the cloned element so it doesn't appear more than once. `$('#dynamicgroup').append($('#dis').clone().removeAttr("id"));` - demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/o6p96mpf/

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked well.Is it possible to loop MVC based dropdownlist using jquery?

Comment: @user3793029 what do you mean by "MVC based dropdown"? A dropdown is a dropdown. You can select it with jquery by it's ID, a CSS class, or even other ways.