# Can we create multiple HTML tables dynamically using for loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I want to create html table dynamically and number of table will be depend upon the response I am getting in array. New table should be created after every 6 elements and table header will be array elements itself.
Expected output is-

```
-------------------------------------
| th1 | th2 | th3 | th4 | th5 | th6 |
-------------------------------------
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
-------------------------------------
```

code for generating table is as below in which consoles are printing properly but elements are not getting create and not getting any error too.

```
'<div id="findingDiv">';

    for(var i=0;i<tables;i++){
         console.log('i-',i);                               
        '<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 10px; border:1px solid black; border-collapse : collapse;font-size: 30px;">'+
            '<thead>'+
                '<tr>';

                for(var k=0;k<6;k++){   

                    '<th id="header" style="color:black; font-size: 12px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center;border-color: rgb(166, 166, 166);"> historyTable[k] </th>';
                    console.log('k-',k);
                }

       '</table> \n';                               
    }
```

Can anybody help me??

I have checked previous solutions which did not worked.
[How to clone() a element n times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835582/how-to-clone-a-element-n-times)
[How to use loop in Jquery to add table multiple times into div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840516/how-to-use-loop-in-jquery-to-add-table-multiple-times-into-div)
[Create a table dynamically using for loop in .html()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085338/create-a-table-dynamically-using-for-loop-in-html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery to add form elements dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744594/how-to-use-jquery-to-add-form-elements-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.append()` method to add `HTML` table to your `DIV` dynamicaly in `for` loop.

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/32qnzakx/2/)

You can use below code.

Below DIV in html:

```
<div id="findingDiv">
</div>
```

Code in jquery. I used jQuery `.ready()` method to create it on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tables = ['th1','th2','th3','th4','th5','th6']

    for(var i=0;i<tables.length;i++){
    var content = "<table><thead><tr>";
        for(var k=0;k<6;k++)
        {
            content += '<th id="header" style="color:black; font-size: 12px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center;border-color: rgb(166, 166, 166);">'+tables[k]+' </th>';                    
        }
        content += "</tr></thead></table><br/>";
        $('#findingDiv').append(content);
    }
 });
```

**I just added the `th`, same way you can add `tr` as well.**

Comment: Yes thnx..But it is working when div findingDiv is defined in html code. I can not create div in html I need to create it dynamically on click event. And in that case this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, in that case, you can create DIV as well in jquery. But you need to use .append(content) on any element, may be a body. Because you can't directly inject element to the DOM.